# AWS Glue - Is it possible to create a custom JDBC connector to WRITE into Salesforce DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

I need to do a POC if it is feasible use AWS Glue to READ data from AWS and WRITE it into Salesforce via JDBC custom connector.

Checking the docs like

[AWS Custom Glue connectors docs :](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-testing-and-deploying-custom-connectors-for-your-data-stores-with-aws-glue/) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-testing-and-deploying-custom-connectors-for-your-data-stores-with-aws-glue/

and the available marketplace options like from CData :

[CData AWS Glue Salesforce Connector](https://www.cdata.com/kb/articles/salesforce-glue-connector.rst?kw=&cpn=2023385644&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=CData_-_Search_-_Branding_-_DSA&utm_content=Branding_-_DSA&utm_term=%7C&kw=&cpn=2023385644&gclid=CjwKCAjw1ICZBhAzEiwAFfvFhG0gbR6XxZ4XgHo0aqIqVHSzcg8Dgxw4v1zTGDsYxdvTga4RGd4SPxoCGnQQAvD_BwE)

It seems that it is only possible to READ from Salesforce and WRITE into AWS data stores. My usecase would be the inverse to update Salesforce objects using AWS Glue.

Does anybody have experience with that or knows if that is feasible with custom connectors?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the reference URL you have provided for CDATA, its mentioned as "Using the CData Glue Connector for Salesforce in AWS Glue Studio, you can easily create ETL jobs to load Salesforce data into an S3 bucket or any other destination. You can also use the Glue Connector to add, update, or delete Salesforce data in your Glue Jobs.".  So technically it should be possible, can you please give a try, and let know the status

Comment: @Yuva I must have missed that section, thanks for highlighting. We decided to go with AWS Appflow for the requirememt. In the unprobable case we subscribe to that Connector and give it a try would update.